# Seeking Tutorials on Geometric Networks

Tags: arcgis-desktop, references, geometric-network

Does anyone know of any tutorials I can download online or anything of the likes that I can use to better my understanding of how to use or create the geometric network?

I'm working on a sewer infrastructure project gathering asset information and believe the geometric network may be the best way to go.

Answer (score 1):

First read the [documentation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/geometric-networks/what-are-geometric-networks-.htm).  That is usually a good place to start.

Or, more generally ['getting started with topologies'](https://www.esri.com/training/catalog/57630430851d31e02a43ee19/getting-started-with-geodatabase-topology/) seeing as Geometric Networks are a kind of topology rule set.  You should have access to this training if your Org has an active ESRI license.

Without knowing the context, working for a Water Utility we are starting to talk about long term plans to switch off of the Geometric Network and switch to the [Utility Network](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/data/utility-network/what-is-a-utility-network-.htm) which is ESRI's new solution to network connectivity and (I believe) is intended to replace the geometric network.

more links from a simple google search:

[Tutorial 5-2: Creating geometric networks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=04vBXU-fuPs)

[Exercise 5: Building a Geometric Network](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/geodatabases/exercise-5-building-a-geometric-network.htm)